# Set default value for variable followed by a non-default variable

Tags: r

So I have an assignment to write an R function to calculate net present value. The requirements go like this:

```
myNPV <- function(vector_cashflow, vector_year, interest_rate)...
```

The assignment requires that this function works regardless of whether the users enter vector_year, and the order of the variables if exactly like above (vector_cashflow, vector_year, interest_rate).
For example:

```
myNPV(1000:3000,1:3,0.02) and myNPV(1000:3000,0.02)
```

work the same.
I have no idea how can this be possible? I tried to set `vector_year = some_value`, but clearly doing so make it ambiguous whether the users want to enter the vector_year or the interest rate.

Comment: Without fragile code that checks to see if the value of an *unnamed* function argument is reasonable (there are cases where this can be unambiguous), this is not possible. Options: (1) put `vector_year` *last* and assign it a default value; or (2) require an empty argument, as is `myNPV(1000:3000, , 0.2)`.

Comment: But trying to incorporate logic such as `if (vector_year < 1900) { interest_rate <- vector_year; vector_year <- defaultyear; ... }` is fairly fragile, and can be difficult to troubleshoot if you aren't familiar enough with the function's makeup.

Comment: Another option: (3) require *named* arguments, as in `myNPV(1000:3000, interest_rate=0.02)`.

Comment: Can we use something like override in C or Java? Or maybe put vector_year as an optional argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it might be "acceptable" to test for argument validity based on its range: I am assuming that the scales of `vector_year` (1900+) and `interest_rate` (between 0 and 1?) are unambiguously different. I do find assumptions like this to be fine until they are not ... and troubleshooting this kind of thing can be problematic.

```r
myNPV <- function(vector_cashflow, vector_year, interest_rate) {
  if (missing(interest_rate)) {
    if (vector_year < 10) { # arbitrary, unlikely you're calculating for 2000 years ago
      interest_rate <- vector_year
      vector_year <- sane_default_value # this is up to you!
    } else {
      stop("'interest_rate' not provided and it is unsafe to guess based on the arguments")
    }
  }
  # rest of your code here ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass `vector_year` as optional arguments. Catch them using `c(...)` and test it with `is.null` and based on that you can perform further calculation.

```
myNPV <- function(vector_cashflow, interest_rate, ...) {
   vector_year <- c(...)
   if(is.null(vector_year)) {
     print("No Vector Year present")
     #Do something here
   }
   else {
     print("Vector Year present")
     #Do something else here
  }
}

myNPV(1000:3000,1:3)
#[1] "No Vector Year present"

myNPV(1000:3000,1:3, 10)
#[1] "Vector Year present"
```